# How to stop a youtube video from playing

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

hi guys messing with the youtube api for android. ive got it all set up and working. im using my firebase database to send all relavent info to my app in the form of a list. all works great the list shows, the video plays from the list. and goes in to full screen ok.. but if i want to click another video in my list after nothing happens. so i assume i have to stop and clear my YouTubePlayerView but i dont know how to do this

this is how i get my strings from firebase

```
 Dl_Strings dlStrings = dataSnapshot.getValue(Dl_Strings.class);
        Downloadscount.add(" " + String.valueOf(dlStrings.downloads));
        AppNameList.add(dlStrings.name);
        urlList.add(dlStrings.url);
```

this is where i grab the url and add it to my youtube player

```
mlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                urlmain = urlList.get(i).toString();
                tag = TAGGER.get(i).toString();


                App_DownLoadCounter();
                YouTubePlayerView myoutubeplayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.youtube);

                YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOninitial;

                mOninitial = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(urlmain);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a part of code is missing from your snippet, but here's why this isn't working:

The YouTube player needs to be initialized only once. `loadVideo` is not called because `onInitializationSuccess` is called only the 1st time you initialize the player.

You could simply keep a reference of `YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer` the first time you initialize it and re use that when you need it.

```
YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  // initialize player here and save 
  // ...
  @Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
     this.youTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
  }

}


// in your listener
mlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
      String videoID = urlList.get(i).toString();
      this.youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID);
  }
}
```

Comment: so how would i recall the initialize function every time a list item is preesed? thanks @Pierfrancesco Soffritti

Comment: the only reference to the player is the one in my onInitializationSuccess method. so how do i reuse this?

Comment: i have tried storing it as a referance at the the top of my code. and it didnt do anthing

Answer (score 2):

According to Android Player API, you can do this using [release()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer) method:

**public abstract void release ()**

> Stop any loading or video playback and release any system resources
>   used by this YouTubePlayer.
>
> Note that after calling this method any further interaction with this
>   YouTubePlayer is forbidden. A new instance must be created to
>   re-enable playback.

Comment: thanks @noogui but when i try to use release it causes an error that says youtube player released cant load video or something similar